# How can I find the probability of possible word combinations for the word TRIANGLES?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My question says,

> If all the letters of TRIANGLES are placed in a row, find the probability that the resulting word:
>
> a) starts with a consonant
>
> b) starts with a T and ends in an A
>
> c) starts with TAN
>
> d) starts with the three vowels in a row

But I am not sure how to solve A through E. Please provide any help you can! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The (education) tag is not meant to be used just because you encountered the problem during your education.  The (education) tag is meant to be for questions *about* education and pedagogy as it relates specifically to mathematics such as "What is the ideal teacher/student ratio?" or "How frequently should tests be administered to gauge progress?"  Almost always such a question would be better suited for MathEducators.se instead

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily assume that every letter is distinct, even if the letters happened to be the same.  (*This is unnecessary here since all the letters of `TRIANGLE` actually /are/ distinct, but it helps to generalize the problem for other ones where you had repeated some repeated letters*)

The probability the first letter is a $T$ is going to be $\frac{1}{9}$ since there are nine letters available and only one of them is a $T$ and each of the nine letters are equally likely to have been the first letter of the word.

Given that the first letter was a $T$, the probability that the second letter is an $R$ is going to be $\frac{1}{8}$ since given that the first letter was a $T$ there are eight remaining letters and each of the eight letters are equally likely to have been the second letter of the word.

The probability that the first letter is a $T$ and the second letter is an $R$ is then $\frac{1}{9}\times \frac{1}{8}$, seen by application of the rule of product for probability.

This could just as easily have been seen by counting techniques.  The number of possible rearrangements of the word is $9!$.  Of these, if we wanted to count the number of arrangements which start with a $T$ followed by an $R$ would be $1\cdot 1\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdots 2\cdot 1 = 7!$, seen by rule of product for counting.  (*There is good reason why rule of product for probability and rule of product for counting are closely related*)

Taking the ratio, we would get a probability of $\frac{7!}{9!}=\frac{7!}{7!\cdot 8\cdot 9} = \frac{1}{9}\times \frac{1}{8}$, just as before.

All of the problems in your list follow similar patterns, noting that in the case of looking at the probability of getting a vowel, you could have more than just the one in the numerator and instead the number of available vowels as the numerator instead...

> $\frac{6}{9}$ to start with a consonant, $\frac{1}{9}\times\frac{1}{8}$ to start with a $T$ and end with an $A$.  I'll leave the others for you to do without checking against my answers.